# Why Railtie initializers are not executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, initializer, railtie

While crafting the [Passenger-Monit](https://github.com/romanbsd/passenger_monit) plugin, I thought that it'll be most appropriate to use the initializer, i.e.

```
module PassengerMonit
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "my_plugin.some_init_task" do
      # my initialization tasks
    end
  end
end
```

However, for some reason the code in the block was never executed.
I finally made a work-around with

```
config.before_initialize {}
```

but I'm curious, why the initializer wasn't executed. What could have prevented it from running?

Answer (score 1):

In your gemfile, did you add

```
gem "Passenger-Monit"
```

Otherwise you need to put it in your load path and require it in your application. 
http://www.igvita.com/2010/08/04/rails-3-internals-railtie-creating-plugins/

Good luck!

Comment: Of course. Otherwise config.before_initialize wouldn't have been run as well.